# Application Class Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am creating an Android app and wish to store a variable in the Application class. The variable signifies which Activity is currently in focus.

I aim to set this variable in `onResume()` and reset it in `onPause()`. Both methods are called as the app initialises. The software crashes on the basis of a Null Pointer Excepetion whenever I run my code, at lines where I try to modify the variable in the Application class. As far as I am aware, it appears to me as though the Application class is `null` even though I have tested the code and know it call the Application class' `onCreate()`.

Am I correct in assuming it is connected to the Application Class not being completely created? Or is it connected to my instantiation of it all? I'm reasonably new to Android and haven't dealt with the Application class before - as far as I can see, I've followed the guides and tutorials correctly. I'm hoping it's a simple mistake.

Any and all advice is greatly appreciated!

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    //[... other initialisations...]

    // Tells software what window is in focus.
    // Reference to Application class
    private MyApplicationClass app = (MyApplicationClass)getApplication();
    private static final int outOfFocus = 0;
    private static final int inFocus = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //[... other code...]
        app.setActivityFocusIndicator(inFocus); //Crashes here
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //[... other code...]
        app.setActivityFocusIndicator(outOfFocus); //Crashes here
    }
}
```

MyApplicationClass.java

```
public class MyApplicationClass extends Application {

    private int activityFocusIndicator;
    /* activityFocusIndicator is here to indicate which activity is in focus.
     * 0 = Nothing in focus (written when pausing.)
     * 1 = MainActivity
     * 2 = ...
     * ...
     */

    public void setActivityFocusIndicator(int activityFocusIndicator) {
        this.activityFocusIndicator = activityFocusIndicator;
    }

    public int getActivityFocusIndicator() {
        return activityFocusIndicator;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("App", "App was created."); // This line is reached.
    }
}
```

Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.someApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
                  android:required="true"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="18"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/TabTheme"
        android:name="com.example.someName.MyApplicationClass" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.someName.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            ...
        </activity>
        <!-- ... [other activities declared]... -->
        <service
            android:name=".BluetoothService"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I can post the LogCat if asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point of this line :

```
private MyApplicationClass app = (MyApplicationClass)getApplication();
```

This variable is probably initialized before the reference returned by `getApplication()` is initialized, and therefore remains null.

Instead of using it, replace each acess to `app` with a local variable.

For example:

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //[... other code...]
    MyApplicationClass app = (MyApplicationClass)getApplication();
    app.setActivityFocusIndicator(inFocus);
}
```

Comment: Sound logic, that's exactly what the issue was, thanks! It's something I'll need to keep in mind when using the class in the future.